# where to look for performance boost in referenced assembly

Tags: c#

We have two internal systems that share databases and perform identical functions.  Each system has it's own .net c# solution.  To reduce code duplication I created a class library project in the one solution that does all of the database work and then in the 2nd solution I was able to reference it.  It works however the 2nd solution is much much slower when using the assembly.

The 1st solution consists of multiple projects, one being the web site project and the other this assembly I've mentioned.  So the web site project references the other project (in the same solution) for the database functionality.  When a page loads that uses this assembly the time is about 28ms.

The 2nd solution simply references the compiled dll of the assembly from solution 1.  When a web page in this project uses the assembly, calling the exact same methods as those in the web page from solution 1, the time is around 3.5-4 seconds.

I've gone through both solutions and made sure that they're both targeting the same framework version (4.6.1).  They're both running in Release mode.  I've removed all referenced assemblies that I can from the assembly in question so it's only referencing System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.Linq, System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq.  The behavior happens when I run it locally and also on our web servers.  I'm really not sure what else to look at or how to diagnose what's causing the 2nd solution to run so much slower.

Comment: Is this difference in performance noticeable every time or only when you call the methods in the referenced assembly for the first time?

Comment: JPI - Just Profile It. And see what is causing this bug in performance. In most cases it is much better than sitting and cracking your head open.

Comment: Manfred, it happens every time.  Eocron, how do I profile it?

Comment: I use JetBrains.dotTrace for this. You can use any profiler you want. You will get entire explanation on time consumed by each concrete function.

Comment: Though the solutions are different, however, check with the queries which are being fired from both of the application. Use Sql server profiler to find out what type of queries are generated & the time taken by them.

Comment: I found the problem.  Although both solutions use the same database, they don't use the same tables.  The tables the 2nd solution uses didn't have the proper indexes set up.  Creating those solved the problem.